# Is it faster to read from Session or calculated a Value a second time

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I'm still working on my first project with ASP and C#. Everything is working fine. The only problem is, that my page is a little bit slow. So I started to optimize the performance of my page.

After improving some things(Connection-Pooling, SQL-Statements, ...) a came a cross a timecalculation. I want it to return the actual calendar week:

```
            CultureInfo myCI = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            System.Globalization.Calendar myCal = myCI.Calendar;
            CalendarWeekRule myCWR = myCI.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule;
            DayOfWeek myFirstDOW = myCI.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
            currentWeek = myCal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, myCWR, myFirstDOW);
```

Now I'm wonering if it is faster for my Page to calculate it once and write it into the session:

```
            Session["WeekToAnalyze"] = currentWeek;
```

And read it on all my following pages like this:

```
            currentWeek= Convert.ToInt32(Session["WeekToAnalyze"].ToString());
```

Or is it faster to calculated it new on every single Page?

Comment: Instead of `CultureInfo myCI = new CultureInfo("en-US");` use `CultureInfo myCI = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");` :)

Comment: I suspect that the different in time will be not much, search on other areas for large delay, the page it self, the scripts that you load, the images you load, the structure of the page.. the cache on the media... At the end you need to create times to read and compare the actually time for both.

Comment: Storing the value to, and reading from, session is a good design anyway, as you are unlikely to re-calculate that value on each page load.

Comment: This is _not_ the bottleneck in your application. Don't go change random bits of code. You need to benchmark, then improve parts that have proven to be slow.

Comment: If anything, there could be a performance degradation, though negligible. Why? Simple, retrieving an item from session state would result in a request being made to the state server, either the Windows Service or SQL server db or any other. I.e. there's some resource access. As for the calculation, that should be fairly quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, there will be no performance improvement in using `Session`.

If you want to improve your performance, you can do the following:

1. Do not use `new CultureInfo()`, use `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo()`:

   ```
   CultureInfo myCI = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
   ```

   According to [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yck8b540(v=vs.110).aspx), `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo`

   > Retrieves a **cached, read-only instance** of a culture using the specified culture name.
2. Store other variables instead of recreating them each time:

   ```
   public static class WeekOfYearProvider
   {
       private static CultureInfo CultureInfo { get; }
       private static Calendar Calendar { get; }

       static WeekOfYearProvider()
       {
           CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
           Calendar = _cultureInfo.Calendar;
       }

       public static int GetWeekOfYear(DateTime dateTime)
       {
           return Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dateTime,
               CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
               CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
       }
   }
   ```

Every time you call `WeekOfYearProvider.GetWeekOfYear`, it will execute only one operation, which is pretty simple, instead of initializing the whole `CultureInfo` object and creating a new `Calendar`.

Comment: I'd recommend against using Sessions as well. It's not 1999 anymore

Comment: @user3036342 what would be your way to go?

Comment: I can't really say since I don't know what kind of performance hits you are taking, however Yeldar Kurmangaliyev has a good suggestion so far. The problem with sessions is that they're in memory. Any changes to the code will or even directories will make it refresh the app pool, which will then have to reinitialize all sessions, potentially losing work. It also has impact on the server resources. A restless approach will work. But your question is a bit suggestive and I think this is the best answer. Since we don't see where your performance is slowing down, can't really suggest better ways